# Groovy, safe way to create MSSQL database

Tags: sql-server, database, groovy, sql-injection

I'm trying to use groovy.sql.Sql to create databases in an MSSQL (Microsoft SQL Server) server. It seem like the prepared statement adds additional quotes around the last parameter breaking the query.

This test code:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource

def host = 'myhost'
def port = '1433'
def database = 'mydatabasename'
def usernameName = 'myusername'
def password = 'mypassword'

def dataSource = new SQLServerDataSource()
dataSource.setURL("jdbc:sqlserver://$host:$port")
dataSource.setUser(username)
dataSource.setPassword(password)

def connection new Sql(dataSource)
connection.execute(
    'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = ?) DROP DATABASE ?',
    [ databaseName, databaseName ]
)
```

Gives the error:

```
Failed to execute: IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = ?) DROP DATABASE ? because: Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.
```

How can I use prepared statements without having it add single quotes around parameter one (DROP DATABASE **?** seem to be rewritten as DROP DATABASE **'?'**) or can I write the query in a different way so that the added single quotes does not produce a syntax error?

I would also be fine with other frameworks, if anyone could give me a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
connection.execute(
    "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = $databaseName) DROP DATABASE ${Sql.expand(databseName)}"
)
```

Comment: Thank you, and Sql.expand would make the query injection safe?

Comment: No, not by itself, but it would make the query work.

Comment: :) Okay, that was not what I was looking for, then I could do concatenation as well, I'll keep looking.